# django {{form.as_p}} results without input widget

Tags: python, django, django-forms

So here's my form :

```
from django import forms

class PostForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(),
    title = forms.CharField(),
```

Here's my view :

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import PostForm

def sign(request):
    form = PostForm()
    return render(request, 'guestbook/sign_extend.html', {'form': form})
```

and my html :

```
{% extends 'guestbook/sign.html' %}

{% block content %}

<form action='.' method ='POST'>{% csrf_token %}

  {{ form.as_p }}

  <button type="submit">submit</button>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

url:

```
from django.urls import path,include
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
path('sign/', views.sign,name='sign'),
```

When I go to the url it only shows me button but no form fields. What am I doing wrong here ? I can't seem to figure that out..please help

Comment: Does `{{ form }}` show it? Do you have any css styles for `p` tags? Does it show in the output source?

Comment: removed,it works,thank you very much!

Comment: @BearBrown, please post your answer (as an answer).

Comment: @YiTsui , mark his answer as accepted when he posts it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should remove the `,` in the form

```
class PostForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField()
    #                      ^^
    title = forms.CharField()
    #                       ^^
```